# Correct syntax of dynamic return type ActionResult<T> use by explicit ActionResult<Contact> and others

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following code, would like to create dynamic return type of ActionResult of function getResponse, so it can be used as a generic function for all other models like ActionResult.ActionResult etc etc.

The reason I am having an explicit return type is because it needs to be working with Swashbuckle openAPI
which response can be in XML, Json, Text... 
and it looks like it only works by using ActionResult

What is the correct syntax of  public async Task> getResponse(HttpResponseMessage results)??? Thanks, guys.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Contact>> Get(string referenceId = "af2f8f37-c1d9-40d3-9f29-08d5dab10621")
    {
        Settings.ReferenceID = referenceId;
        //same as get a single Contact;
        var url = Settings.PutContactUrl;
        Log.Information($"Endpoint hit: {url}");

        var requestData = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri(url),
        };
        var results = await _client.SendAsync(requestData);
        return getResponse(results);

        if (!results.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            return StatusCode((int)results.StatusCode, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(results.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result));

        //need to cast type to provide xml result
        var contact = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Contact>(results.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        //var abc = _mapper.Map<Contact>(contact);

        return StatusCode((int)results.StatusCode, contact);
    }

    [NonAction]
    public async Task<ActionResult<T>> getResponse(HttpResponseMessage results)
    {
       if (results.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            switch (results.StatusCode)
            {
                case HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
                    return StatusCode((int)results.StatusCode, results.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                default:
                    return StatusCode((int)results.StatusCode, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(results.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result));
            }
        }

        return StatusCode((int)results.StatusCode, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(results.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result));
    }
```

Comment: Just return `IActionResult`, that works with Swagger and Swashbucle

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: IActionResult does not give explicit return response from swash buckle, I can set the attribute of typeof(Contact) but still doesn't work